# Telegram Bot: Sending Multiple Images to webhook from app

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

there seems to be issue with sending multiple images from telegram mobile to webhook server. Whenever I send multiple images for example i send 5 images in bulk, webhook keeps on receiving images for more than 20 times. What possible can issue can be?

**Update**

```
$updates = Telegram::getWebhookUpdates();
Log::debug("Telegram Update: " . $updates);
```

Code is as simple as above. I get Images object in logs. 
Thanks

Comment: please provide your server code

Comment: @Fribu please check

Comment: Might be a problem with the library, did you followed the tutorial or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, you answer to Telegram Bot API with not 200 OK in HTTP status. That's why it continues making requests to your webhook.

Comment: Yes, It seems so. I am looking into it.

Comment: @TalhaMalik, you might mark my answer as a solution of your problem. Thanks ;)

Comment: Yes it was the problem. Somewhere in my code. Thanks pointing it out.